# How can we apply future recurring payment in stripe payment gateway in php

Tags: php, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripe-connect

I am working on subscription, i want to do subscription from future date, i did code for that, but i am not sure is it correct or not, here i have added my code, can anyone please look in this code and tell me i am correct or not, or you can also you give your thoughts on that, here is my subscription code.

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
    'source' => $token,
    'description'=> 'Test Customer',
    'email' => 'NIKULTAKA@GMAIL.com',
    'plan' => $plan_id,
));
// Charge the order:
$dateTime = new DateTime('2018-07-10');
$date_timestamp = $dateTime->format('U');
$charge = \Stripe\Subscription::create(array(
    'customer' => $customer->id,
    "items" => array(
        array(
            "plan" => $plan_id,
        ),
    ),
    "billing_cycle_anchor"=> $date_timestamp
));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about your code, but I can give you some tips.

Implement recurring payment can be harder than you expect.

You can use other payment gateway, the [recurly](https://recurly.com/) can make you life easier. Here you can see a [client api in PHP for recurly](https://github.com/recurly/recurly-client-php)